# UDF: apply a function on Dataframe scala

Tags: scala, datetime, user-defined-functions

I have a scala function, compute the a difference between tow date, that taking two `LocalDateTime` as parameters:

I have a dataFrame that contain tow field start_date and finish_date.

I want construst an UDF "may be" to apply the function toEquals on my dataframe especially on the é field `start_date` and `finish_date` to compute the difference between them. But the type of start_date and finish_date are String.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I edited my question.

Comment: can you also share some sample rows from `input_table`? and what are `adjust` and `toEnd` functions

Comment: I changed it. Thank you

Comment: try my answer below and let me know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested the code yet but *using your `toEquals` logic in a `udf` function* should be enough as

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def toEquals = udf((rd1: String, rd2: String) => {
  val d1 = adjust(LocalDateTime.parse(rd1, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER))
  val d2 = adjust(LocalDateTime.parse(rd2, DATE_TIME_FORMATTER), asc = false)     
  if (d1.isAfter(d2)) 0.hours.toString
  else if (d1.toLocalDate.isEqual(d2.toLocalDate)) {
    (toEnd(d1.toLocalTime) - toEnd(d2.toLocalTime)).toString
  }
  else {
    (toEnd(d1.toLocalTime) + jourOuvree(d1.toLocalDate.plusDays(1), d2.toLocalDate.minusDays(1)) * 8.hours + toStart(d2.toLocalTime)).toString
  }
})
```

and you can call the `udf` function as

```
input_table.withColumn("toEquals", toEquals($"start_date",$"finish_date"))
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. scala> input_os_historystep.withColumn("toEquals", toEquals($"start_date",$"finish_date"))
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration is not supported
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:756)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:694)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:3200)

Comment: the error message is clear enough you will have to convert your FiniteDuration object to the supported types. [supported types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49641733/5880706) You will have to return by converting the FiniteDuration to any of the types

Comment: you mean I should convert it to LocalDateTime ?
Because I have a class formatter that take a parameters FiniteDuration, I edited my question.
Thank you very much

Comment: Just change the object to String . I have updated my answer by using .toString. Please try that

Comment: I'm sorry for this disturb, your solution is magnific, but when I do input_table.show()  it do not add the new column toEquals, on the other hand  it increment in the number of the column by +1 but it do not display it, also not in prinntSchema

Comment: How can I display it. Thank you

Comment: I asked a new question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49668142/withcolumn-display-a-new-column-datetime

Comment: Yes, thank you. I asked another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49693831/check-if-the-day-is-holiday-in-scala

Comment: Can you give an answer for my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49804517/sparkcontext-in-sparksession/49804628#49804628   Thank you very much