# WithColumn: display a new column dateTime

Tags: scala, datetime, user-defined-functions

I have a scala function, compute the a difference between tow date, that taking two `LocalDateTime` as parameters:

I applied the function on 2 fields of my DataFrame.

It seems add the new column because my dataframe contain `7 fields` and it display `8 fields` after applying the function toEquals.
But when I do : `dfWithToEquals.printSchema()`
It display this error:

Someone can help how can I resolve this error to display the new column that contain the difference between these 2 dates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_table.withColumn` returns a new DataFrame. So, to display it:

```
val dfWithToEquals = input_table.withColumn("toEquals", toEquals($"start_date",$"finish_date"))
dfWithToEquals.printSchema()
dfWithToEquals.show()
```

*Update*

To resolve the `Task not serializable` exception: objects passed to Spark must be serializable. Here the `DATE_TIME_FORMATTER` reference is created outside the `udf` and it is not serialisable. Try to move its instantiation inside the function:

```
def toEquals = udf((rd1: String, rd2: String) => {
  val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
  val d1 = adjust(LocalDateTime.parse(rd1, formatter))
  val d2 = adjust(LocalDateTime.parse(rd2, formatter ), asc = false)
  // remaining code unchanged
})
```

*End-of-update*

Comment: scala> val DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") with Serializable<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
val DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") with Serializable
                                                                             ^

scala> val DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") with Serializable
<console>:124: error: illegal inheritance from final class DateTimeFormatter       val DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatter("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") with Serializable